# @IFTTT: How to replace the domain in the EntryURL fed by a RSS source?

Tags: youtube, if-this-then-that, proxy

In "If this then that" I would like to replace youtube.com by invidio.us or [similar](https://alternativeto.net/software/invidious/) services, which can pass youtube videos through a proxy. How can I do this without the need to create a self-hosted webhook? Is there any way (perhaps a web app) to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

invidio.us offers its own RSS feed.